# NoMethodError in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I started a Rails app which worked. But after upgrading to rails 4.1.4, I got NoMethodError in TyperController#index undefined method `first' for Typer:Module in app/controllers/typer_controller.rb: line 35

```
@typer = Typer.first
```

I googled a little bit and have done all the precautions that I have found, but of course I missed something, just don't know what.

My Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

My config/application.rb

```
require "active_model/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Typer
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end
end
```

My model file typer.rb

```
class Typer
  include Mongoid::Document
#  include Mongoid::Timestamps
    field :name, type: String
    field :convert, type: Hash 
#  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a classic example of a name clash.

Module `Typer` gets loaded first (it's an app namespace, after all). After that, any reference to `Typer` will resolve to that module. Your model will not be (auto-)loaded, ever.

Solution is simple: just rename either the main module or the model.